# angularjs 12 : how to drag start the element using drag handle element only

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need to drag start the selected element using drag-handle icon only. note that drag-handle icon element is positined as absolute.

for achieve that on MouseDown Event on that Drag Handle Icon. I'm getting the selected element id from service & find the selected element by id attribute.

after find the element by id, I'm programtically Trigger the drag event for the selected element

```
const selectedElemet: HTMLElement;
selectedElement.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('dragstart'));
```

when I trigger dragstart event for selected element I'am getting logs in console from my Dropable Directive. but after drag start nothing works. after dragstart event dragover, dragenter, dragend, drop no one works.

here is [**my stackblitz url. You can Test This on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-version-n4xvi4?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2FpageBuild%2Fcomponents%2Fpage-builder-ui%2Fpage-builder-ui.component.ts)

[image: SnaptShot of Example Output what I want]

**page-builder-ui component**

> page-builder-ui.component.html

```
<div class="page-builder-container">
  <div class="page-builder-main-body">
    <div
      class="page-builder-main-section-container"
      [attr.is-editable-mode]="!isPreviewMode"
    >
      <div
        class="page-builder-main-section"
        [style.width]="
          this.isPreviewMode && previewModeDeviceWidth
            ? previewModeDeviceWidth + 'px'
            : ''
        "
      >
        <app-page-container></app-page-container>
        <div
          class="selected-component-toolbar-items"
          id="selected-component-toolbar-items"
        >
          <div class="component-toolbar-items">
            <div class="toolbar-items-action">
              <span
                class="material-symbols-outlined action-icon"
                (dragstart)="handleDragStart($event)"
                (dragover)="dragOver($event)"
                draggable="true"
              >
                &#10021;
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="toolbar-items-action">
              <span class="material-symbols-outlined action-icon">
                &#10006;
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> page-builder-ui.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PageBuilderService } from '../../../pageBuild/services/page-builder.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-builder-ui',
  templateUrl: './page-builder-ui.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-builder-ui.component.scss'],
})
export class PageBuilderUiComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private pageBuilderService: PageBuilderService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  handleDragStart(event: Event) {
    // Hide the action toolbar element
    const toolbarElement = document.getElementById(
      'selected-component-toolbar-items'
    );
    if (toolbarElement) {
      // toolbarElement.style.opacity = '0';

      // Get the selected element ID from your service method
      const selectedElemId = this.pageBuilderService
        .getSelectedElementIdSubject()
        .getValue();
      // Find the selected element in the DOM using its ID
      const selectedElement = document.querySelector(
        '[draggable-id="' + selectedElemId + '"]'
      );
      if (selectedElement) {
        console.log(selectedElement);
        // Trigger the drag event for the selected element
        selectedElement.dispatchEvent(new DragEvent('dragstart'));
      }
    }

    // Prevent default behavior
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  dragOver(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

> page-builder-ui.component.scss

```
.page-builder-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-builder-main-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.page-builder-main-section-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: auto;

  .page-builder-main-section {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

    .selected-component-toolbar-items {
      display: none;
      margin-top: -25px;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 12px;
      background-color: rgba(38, 128, 235, 1);
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      z-index: 1;

      &.show {
        display: block;
      }

      .component-toolbar-items {
        pointer-events: all;
        .toolbar-items-action {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 3px;
          cursor: pointer;

          .action-icon {
            font-size: 16px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Directives**

> selectable.directive.ts

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {
  Directive,
  HostBinding,
  HostListener,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { PageBuilderService } from '../../pageBuild/services/page-builder.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSelectable]',
})
export class SelectableDirective implements OnInit {
  public readonly elemSelAttrPrefix = 'select-elem-';
  @Input() elementId: string | undefined;

  selected: boolean = false;
  selectableId: string = '';
  selectedElemIdSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private pageBuilderService: PageBuilderService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.elementId) {
      this.selectableId = this.elementId;
    }

    this.selectedElemIdSubscription = this.pageBuilderService
      .getSelectedElementIdSubject()
      .subscribe((val) => {
        this.selected = false;
        if (this.elementId) {
          this.selected = this.elementId == val;
        }
      });
  }

  @HostBinding('class.selected') get selectedClass() {
    return this.selected;
  }
  @HostBinding('attr.selectable-elem-id')
  public get selectableElemIdAttr(): string {
    return this.elemSelAttrPrefix + this.selectableId;
  }

  isEventOnCurrentElement(event: MouseEvent | DragEvent): boolean {
    // console.log(event.target, this.getNearestParentId(event));
    const selectableId = this.elemSelAttrPrefix + this.selectableId;
    if (this.getNearestParentId(event) == selectableId) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.isEventOnCurrentElement(event)) {
      this.pageBuilderService.selected(this.elementId);
      // on click I update the top & left position of absolute positioned toolbar.
      // Inside toolbar there is a drag-handle (<span>drag_indicator</span>)
      this.showSelectedComponentToolbarItems(this.elementId);
    }
  }

  /**
   * show component toolbar & update position of toolbar based on selected element
   * @param selectedId
   */
  showSelectedComponentToolbarItems(selectedId?: string): void {
    if (selectedId) {
      const toolBarElem: HTMLElement | null = this.document.querySelector(
        '#selected-component-toolbar-items'
      );
      if (toolBarElem) {
        const selectedElem: HTMLElement | null = this.document.querySelector(
          '[selectable-elem-id="' + this.elemSelAttrPrefix + selectedId + '"]'
        );
        if (
          selectedElem &&
          selectedElem.id !== 'page-builder-droppable-main-container-area'
        ) {
          const parentElemPos =
            toolBarElem.parentElement?.getBoundingClientRect();
          const selectedElemPos: DOMRect = selectedElem.getBoundingClientRect();
          if (selectedElemPos && parentElemPos) {
            toolBarElem.classList.add('show');
            toolBarElem.style.top =
              selectedElemPos.top - (parentElemPos.top - 4) + 'px';
            toolBarElem.style.left =
              selectedElemPos.left - parentElemPos.left + 'px';
          }
        } else {
          toolBarElem.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  getNearestParentId(event: MouseEvent): string | undefined {
    let currentElem: Element | null | undefined = event.target as Element;
    let checkId: string | null | undefined = undefined;
    while (!checkId) {
      checkId = currentElem?.getAttribute('selectable-elem-id');
      currentElem = currentElem?.parentElement;
    }
    return checkId;
  }
}
```

> dropable.directive.ts

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import {
  ElementRef,
  Renderer2,
  Directive,
  HostBinding,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  Inject,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropable]',
})
export class DropableDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() elementId!: string;
  @Input() isDraggable: boolean = true;
  @Input() canDrop: boolean = true;

  draggableId!: string;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.elementId) {
      this.draggableId = this.elementId;
    } else {
      this.draggableId = Math.random().toString();
    }
    this.el.nativeElement.classList.add('page-builder-drop-area');
  }

  @HostBinding('attr.draggable') public get draggableAttribute(): boolean {
    return this.isDraggable;
  }

  @HostBinding('attr.draggable-id') public get draggableElemIdAttr(): string {
    return this.draggableId;
  }

  isEventOnCurrentElement(event: MouseEvent | DragEvent): boolean {
    if (
      (event.target as Element)?.getAttribute('draggable-id') ==
      this.draggableId
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @HostListener('dragstart', ['$event'])
  onDrag(event: DragEvent) {
    if (this.isDraggable) {
      if (this.isEventOnCurrentElement(event)) {
        event.dataTransfer?.setData('text/plain', this.elementId);
        console.log('dragstart', this.elementId);
        const elmStatus = this.document.getElementById('evtStatus');
        if (elmStatus) {
          elmStatus.textContent = 'dragstart event. Drag Started';
        }
      }
    }
    // event.stopPropagation()
  }

  @HostListener('dragend', ['$event'])
  onDragEnd(event: DragEvent) {
    if (this.isEventOnCurrentElement(event)) {
      console.log('dragend event');
    }
  }

  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  onDragOver(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.isEventOnCurrentElement(event)) {
      console.log('dragover', event);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event'])
  onDragLeave(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  @HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  onDrop(event: DragEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.isEventOnCurrentElement(event)) {
      const elmId = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
      console.log('drop event', elmId);
      const elmStatus = this.document.getElementById('evtStatus');
      if (elmStatus) {
        elmStatus.textContent =
          "Drop event. dropped element's id is : " + elmId;
        setTimeout(function () {
          elmStatus.textContent = '';
        }, 5000);
      }

      alert('Drop Event. dropped Elem Id is : ' + elmId);
    }
  }
}
```

---

here is [**my stackblitz url. You can Test This on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-version-n4xvi4?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2FpageBuild%2Fcomponents%2Fpage-builder-ui%2Fpage-builder-ui.component.ts)

**Thank You**